# Backup Files (robocopy) | Error on files in-use

Tags: windows-7, command-line, backup, robocopy

`OS: Windows 7 x64 (HomePremium)
CMD: >robocopy [source] [destination] -options`

`$ robocopy "C:\Users\itzme\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\geo2eich.default" "E:\download\internet\firefox\geo2eich.default" /MIR /SEC`

I use *Robocopy* within *Windows* to backup my files/drives. The problem is that i'm receiving errors for destinations that are currently in-use such as (*examples of which files are in-use during scheduled run include*):

Foobar2000 (portable): **_running**-file

Firefox: **parent.lock**-file

Because I have this task scheduled to run daily I most likely have these programs up and running by the time of the scheduled-run, so it conflicts consistently.

So my question is, is there a way to by-pass files that can't be copied? Because in this particular situation I don't need to backup these 'live-files' they don't contain any significant data that I atleast need anyways.

Comment: Are you able to post the robocopy options you are using?

Comment: @PJMahoney, I've added the command along with it's parameters in the original post (only of which include `/MIR` & `SEC`. It seems I could just retry it once & have it wait very shortly with `/R:1` `/W:1`

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to use the `/R:<number of retry>` and `/W:<time before next retry>` options.  If the destination you are transferring to is on a network or unstable type of storage you can add more retry times and increase the wait.  However I have found that the usual `/R:1` and `/W:1` works fine in most cases.  If you don't specify these options the default retry is 1 million and default wait time is 30 seconds (holy cow!)

I would also be very careful of the `/MIR` option.  This will make an exact copy of the source to the destination.  **If you run this command a second time** and the source files have changed **it will make another EXACT copy**.  This becomes a problem if you delete a file from the source and wanted to keep that one on the destination (say a backup history of types), the `/MIR` option will remove the file from the destination.

**A Better way** is to use the `/E` option instead of `/MIR`. It basically does the same thing but keeps files in the destination unless they are over written.

Since you have also used the `/SEC` option, this may not actually keep file persmission in tack.  In addition I would include `/SECFIX`.  I've used this when migrating users home folders on servers and the permissions kept with `/SEC /SECFIX`

Lastly you can create a log file to view the results after the command has finished with.  First choice, create a new log file `/LOG:<filename>`, second choice, append to the end of an exisiting log file `/LOG+:<filename>`

**My suggested full command would be**

```
robocopy "C:\Users\itzme\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\geo2eich.default" "E:\download\internet\firefox\geo2eich.default" /E /R:1 /W:1 /SEC /SECFIX /LOG+:"C:\temp\robocopy.log"
```

Here is a link to the full robocopy documenation from MS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Or at a command line just run `robocopy /?` and it will output the options.  The output looks a bit daunting at first but you will soon see that it is split into sections, ie COPY OPTIONS, RETRY OPTIONS, etc.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i've not switched to `/E` rather than `/MIR`. I've managed to by-pass the files that were in-use with the `/R:` & `/W:` parameters and am now able to successfully backup my files. BUT, as far as logging goes, why do people prefer it to be in ~/temp? Wouldn't that directory be flushed after a pc-restart?

Comment: I just used the temp directory as an example.  If you were going to backup often you might want to make a dedicated directory for the log files.  I guess sometimes you would just quickly review the log and then not need to see it again.  This is all personal preference though.